# Is there any real difference between using and not using extend

Tags: renpy

Until a few days ago I thought I knew how to display sprites with side images and have "talks" on screen where the sprite and side image change expressions. That is until I found the extend command.

Now what I'm unsure of if using extend (way 2 below) is different from not using it (example way 1 below). Thus is the outcome there in all cases the same, or are there side effects by one of the 2 ways that are not to be seen at first glance (or short: are there any real differences aside from the code used for the 2 ways?)

**Way 1: How I handled things so far**

```
Jason happy "Hey that is a good idea"
Eila grinning "yeah sure....."
Eila angry ".....are you NUTS?!"
```

**Way 2: extend version**

```
show Jason happy
Jason "Hey that is a good idea"
show Eila grinning
Eila "yeah sure....."
show Eila angry
extend ".....are you NUTS?!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you didn't get your answer yet:

`extend` adds to the previous line after mouse click.

So when you're at the `"yeah sure....."` line and you click, `Way 1` would be something like:

```
Eileen: ".....are you NUTS?!"
```

While `Way 2` would be:

```
Eileen: "yeah sure..........are you NUTS?!"
```

Reference: https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/dialogue.html